# Copy and paste a file programmaticaly

Tags: c#, file, copy

***Question Background:***

I need to copy and paste (move) a file from one folder location to another.

***Issue:***

The `File.Copy` method of `System.IO` requires the that both parameters are of known file locations. I only know one file path location - in this case `localDevPath`. `localQAPath` is the folder path where I want the copied file to be moved too.

```
string localDevPath = @"C:\Folder1\testFile.cs";

string localQaPath = @"C:\Folder2\";

File.Copy(localDevPath, localQaPath);
```

Can anyone tell me how to go about carrying out this 'copy and paste' method I'm trying to implement.

Comment: How about [`File.Move`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: What's the problem with your code? You always know both file locations, since you can't copy a file if you don't know where it is, and you can't copy it somewhere you don't know. If the "problem" is that your QaPath is just a folder, the standard is to name the new file the same as the previous file. Just get the substring after the last `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that these are user-provided paths and you can't simply include the filename in the second path, then you need to extract the last path element from `localDevPath` and then add it to `localQaPath`. You could probably do that with `Path.GetFilename`.

Comment: Can I simply append 'TestFile.cs' to the 'localQaPath' and even though it dose not currently excist in 'Folder2' it will be overwritten and added?

Comment: Yes, that's in fact the simplest solution. I don't understand what you mean by overwritten, though. How can it be overwritten if it doesn't exist? As for exactly what will happen if it does exist, I would check the `File.Copy` documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
string localDevPath = @"C:\Folder1\testFile.cs";
string localQaPath = @"C:\Folder2\";
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(localDevPath);
fi.MoveTo(Path.Combine(localQaPath, fi.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the issue here is that the filename is variable, in which case, you could do something like this to extract the filename from the full path of localDevPath:

```
string localDevPath = @"C:\Folder1\testFile.cs";
string localQaPath = @"C:\Folder2\";
string[] tokens = localDevPath.Split(@"\");
localQaPath += tokens[tokens.Length-1];

File.Copy(localDevPath, localQaPath);
```

Documentation on File.Copy is on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). There is an overload that accepts a boolean, to allow overwriting if there is a naming conflict.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is move the file from one location to another, the method you are looking for is MoveTo. It is a method of the FileInfo class. There is a very complete example in the MSDN Library here: [FileInfo.MoveTo Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.moveto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)